# Time Series and MA-model look equal in R

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I am using the forecast package of R and I created a MA(1) model by using the ARIMA function. I plotted the time series itself ($x variable of the ma_model), the model itself ($fitted variable of the ma_model) and the residuals (residuals variable of the ma_model). Strangely the time series looks equal to the model altough there are nonegative residuals. Here is the code that I used:

```
library(forecast)
ma_model<-Arima(ts(generationData$Price[1:200]), order=c(0,1,0))
plot(ma_model$fitted, main = "Fitted")
plot(ma_model$x, main = "X")
plot(ma_model$residuals, main = "Residuals")
```

Here is the result
[image]

Basically the model can't be equal to the real time series especially when having residuals. Can anyone explain this to me? I'd appreciate every comment.

**Update**: I tried to use the order=c(0,0,20) so I have a MA(20) or AR(20) model (I am not sure which parameters stands for MA and AR). Now the fitted curve and the original time series look quite equal (but not exactly equal). Is this possible and usual? I'd appreciate every further comment.

Any comments on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your output, but from the code it seems that you just took the difference in the model, not the MA.

I think it should be `order=c(0,0,1)` instead of `order=c(0,1,0)` for building the MA model.

Comment: Thanks Kashyap Dobariya for your answer (I upvoted it). I now use order = c(0,0,1) and now the residuals and the fitted curve look equal. Can this be possible?

Comment: Hi Kashyap. Any comments to my last comment? I'd appreciate any further answer from you.

Comment: Can it be possible for a MA(1) model that the residuals and the fitted curve look equal?

Comment: According to my knowledge if that's the case that residuals and the fitted curve looks equal, you need to apply more parameters in model creation like add parameters in order=c(p,d,q), the final result should be the white noise in case of residuals.

Comment: Also if both the graphs are showing the same result then your model is not capturing the enough variance, for the residuals it should left with just white noise.

Comment: Hi all, it's me again. I tried to use the order=c(0,0,20) so I have a MA(20) or AR(20) model (I am not sure which parameters stands for MA and AR). Now the fitted curve and the original time series look quite equal (but not exactly equal). Is this possible and usual? I'd appreciate every further comment.